# Model binding to a List - how to handle inserts

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, list, binding

I am referring to this post from Phil Haack http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx  I need to do the same but what if I need to insert records in the list, at any index I wanted? How do I keep the indexes in sync short of doing some Javascript and updating all indexes?

```
<form method="post" action="/Home/Create">

<input type="text" name="[0].Title" value="Curious George" />
<input type="text" name="[0].Author" value="H.A. Rey" />
<input type="text" name="[0].DatePublished" value="2/23/1973" />

<input type="text" name="[1].Title" value="Code Complete" />
<input type="text" name="[1].Author" value="Steve McConnell" />
<input type="text" name="[1].DatePublished" value="6/9/2004" />
<!-- I want to insert a record here by adding the fields through JavaScript -->
<input type="text" name="[2].Title" value="The Two Towers" />
<input type="text" name="[2].Author" value="JRR Tolkien" />
<input type="text" name="[2].DatePublished" value="6/1/2005" />

<input type="submit" />
```

I didn't quite understand how I would use the "Non-Sequential Indices" described on that blog post for doing stuff like inserting records to specific index.

Any ideas?